# How to debug python programs in Neovim [Astrovim distro]?

Tags: neovim, debugging, neovim-python-client, astronvim

I have install neovim 0.8.3. I am using Astrovim distribution.

I have installed all the necessary plugin. I have executed

```
:TSInstall python
:LspInstall pyright
:DapInstall python
```

But still when I tried to do debug, it shows the below error.

I don't know where should i add python dap configuration in Astrovim configuration list.

In which file I need to add python dap configuration to enable debugging?

[image]